# Sort R rows based on the number of repetition

Tags: r, sorting, rep

I have a table like:

```
    me    mine    
1   z       ghm     
2   d       gwm
3   d       gom
4   d       gum
5   f       gom
6   g       gum
7   h       gom
8   t       ghm
9   y       gom
10  u       gom
```

how can I sort these data based on the repetition in mine clumn, note: all start with "g" and end with "m". the result im looking for is like"

```
     me    mine    
1   d       gom     
2   f       gom
3   h       gom
4   y       gom
5   u       gom
6   d       gum
7   g       gum
8   t       ghm
9   z       ghm
10  d       gwm
```

or somthing like this:

```
gom    d,f,h,y,u    
gum    d,g,    
ghm    t,z     
gwm      z,d
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (`df` is your data.frame):

```
   indices<-match(df$mine,names(sort(table(df$mine),decreasing=TRUE)))
   df[order(indices,df$me),]
```

There is a reason you want `gum` before `ghm`?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another one-liner:

```
split(df, df$mine)[order(sapply(split(df, df$mine), NROW), decreasing = TRUE)]
```

If you want to have it in `data.frame` format, just add a `do.call(rbind,.)`.

Answer (score -1):

What about something like that

```
> z = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'z','a')
> sort(table(z))
z
c z a b 
1 1 2 3 
>
```