# Tabulating in a different manner in R

Tags: r

This question is related to [Sort R rows based on the number of repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279282/sort-r-rows-based-on-the-number-of-repetition)

From following data frame:

```
> ddf
   aa  bb
1   c efg
2   d cde
3   d abc
4   c abc
5   b efg
6   b cde
7   c abc
8   c abc
9   c cde
10  b cde
> 
> 
> dput(ddf)
structure(list(aa = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), bb = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("abc", "cde", 
"efg"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("aa", "bb"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can sort it:

```
> ddf[order(ddf$bb),]
   aa  bb
3   d abc
4   c abc
7   c abc
8   c abc
2   d cde
6   b cde
9   c cde
10  b cde
1   c efg
5   b efg
```

and I can tabulate like following:

```
> t(with(ddf, table(aa,bb)))
     aa
bb    b c d
  abc 0 3 1
  cde 2 1 1
  efg 1 1 0
```

But I want to have output like following:

```
abc  c c c d
cde  b b c d
eft  b c
```

I tried:

```
ll = list()
for(xx in unique(ddf$bb)) {
 ll[[length(ll)+1]] = xx
 ll[[length(ll)+1]] = ddf[ddf$bb==xx,]$aa
}

ll
[[1]]
[1] "efg"

[[2]]
[1] c b
Levels: b c d

[[3]]
[1] "cde"

[[4]]
[1] d b c b
Levels: b c d

[[5]]
[1] "abc"

[[6]]
[1] d c c c
Levels: b c d
```

But I cannot combine these to have output like:

```
abc  c c c d
cde  b b c d
eft  b c
```

The b,c,d etc should be sorted as shown above. Thanks for your help.

Edit: 
It works with the answer provided by @Richard Scriven:

```
> aggregate(aa ~ bb, ddf, function(x) paste(sort(x)))
   bb         aa
1 abc c, c, c, d
2 cde b, b, c, d
3 efg       b, c
```

But why following (which I had tried earlier) gives only numbers?

```
> aggregate(aa ~ bb, ddf, function(x) sort(x))
   bb         aa
1 abc 2, 2, 2, 3
2 cde 1, 1, 2, 3
3 efg       1, 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `aggregate` with an anonymous function to `sort` then `paste` the values.

```
aggregate(aa ~ bb, ddf, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = " "))
#    bb      aa
# 1 abc c c c d
# 2 cde b b c d
# 3 efg     b c
```

Comment: Yes it works! Can you clarify a point I have added in my question above?

Comment: It's because `aa` is a factor variable and so `sort` converts them to their numeric values.